# GraphicImage não mostra outra Foto

Tags: primefaces-3.5

Ola,

Tenho uma tela de cadastro, onde tem um campo pra informar a foto. Isso consegui fazer mas quando coloco a foto errada e vou selecionar novamente ela não atualiza. quando saio do Dialog e volto a imagem esta lá. Como fazer para mudar sem ter que sair do dialog?

Segue o que eu fiz:
Botão que pega a imagem.

```
<p:fileUpload auto="true" label="Selecionar"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png)$/" multiple="false" update="imagem"
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.fileUploadAction}"/>
                        <br />
```

Componente que recebe a imagem:

```
<p:graphicImage width="200x" height="250px" id="imagem" styleClass="circular"
                            value="#{fileUploadController.imagem}" />
```

Classe fileUploadController:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadController") @SessionScoped  public class UploadController {

private String nomeArquivoSelecionado;  
private StreamedContent imagem;  

public StreamedContent getImagem() {  
    return imagem;  
}  

public void setImagem(StreamedContent imagem) {  
    this.imagem = imagem;  
}  

public String getNomeArquivoSelecionado() {  
    return nomeArquivoSelecionado;  
}  

public void setNomeArquivoSelecionado(String nomeArquivoSelecionado) {  
    this.nomeArquivoSelecionado = nomeArquivoSelecionado;  
}  

public void fileUploadAction(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    try {  
        setNomeArquivoSelecionado(event.getFile().getFileName());  
        imagem = new DefaultStreamedContent(event.getFile().getInputstream());  
    } catch (IOException ex) {  
        //Logger.getLogger(FileUploadController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
    }  
}
```

}